# 削除ボタンがはみ出ている

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

### タグの削除

[image: タグの削除]

### コメントの削除

[image: コメントの削除]

Google Chrome 37.0.2062.94 / Mac OS X 10.9.5 / Retina

追記:

ロードされているCSS: http://cdn.sstatic.net/jameta/all.css?v=e5eb64e67373  
サイトのバージョン: rev 2014.10.16.1945

Comment: これは解決できたと思うが、確認よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @jmac メインでは解決していますが、メタではまだ再現します。[バッジの丸ぽちの件](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BF%E3%81%AE%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%B8%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7%E3%81%A7%E9%87%91%E9%8A%80%E9%8A%85%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%B8%E3%81%BD%E3%81%A1%E3%81%8C%E9%9A%A0%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B#comment138_231) と同じ原因の問題のようで、リンク先のコメントにあるようにCSSをいじったら解決しました